# saving a string to internal memory then displaying it

Tags: android, json, memory, save, internal

hey there i have this code that should save a file from sql server when you click the first button, and then display it when the second button is pressed. first button seems to work but the second button causes it to crash here is my code

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

String result = "";
InputStream is = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    Button saveFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.downloadBtn);
    saveFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            returnJson();

        }
    });


    Button showFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showBtn);
    showFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            TextView showText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showView);


        String FILENAME = "Story_One";
        String showStoryNames = "";

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fis.read(showStoryNames.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




        }
    });

    //end of onCreate
}

public void returnJson(){


    try{
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/textures_story_list.php");

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e) {
        //one.setText("error3");
    }

    try{


        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"), 8);                      
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();

    }catch(Exception e) {
        //one.setText("error2");            
        }

    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        String storyNames = "";
        for(int i = 0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                storyNames += jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("story_name") + "\n"; 

        String FILENAME = "Story_One";
        String string = storyNames;

        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(string.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        }
        }
    catch(JSONException e) {
        //one.setText("error1");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return;

//end of returnJson()   
}



//end of method body
}
```

i need someone to tell me if the code is write for saving to internal is right and also why button 2 crashes.

ok so this is the code im working off

```
    public void returnJson(){

    TextView one = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    try{
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/story_one.php");

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e) {
        one.setText("error3");
    }

    try{


        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"), 8);                      
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();

    }catch(Exception e) {
        one.setText("error2");          
        }

    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        String storyNames = "";
        for(int i = 0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                storyNames += jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("story_name") + "\n"; 
        }
        one.setText(storyNames);
    }
    catch(JSONException e) {
        one.setText("error1");
    }
        return;


//end of returnJson()   
}
```

so can anyone tell me what codes i dont need and what i do need and where to put it to be able to save the result from story_one.php, and whether its ok to leave it as json as im converting it later when the story_one file is being used

Comment: post your error log when it crashes

Comment: what is the error / stacktrace??

Comment: how do i post error log?

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences if you want to store only a single string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this following code to write a string to the file.

```
try{

String text = "String that goes in the file"
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("filename.txt",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
osw.write(text);
int len = text.length();
osw.flush();
osw.close();
}catch(IOException ioe){
}
```

Comment: i have a SQL DB that holds a list of stories that outputs in json, when they press download i want the new story to be saved on their phone so that it can be view through our java class

Comment: so if your code works to save, then how can i display that saved file

Comment: To can use some spliter in your string and save it in a file, later you can split the string to populate the list. hope this helped you

Comment: rakshi i added the codes i use to get the external data from mySQL

Comment: later in the app the story_one needs to be filled into a textview when they choose to read that story. so bacicly my app users can save a story from mySQL DB, choose to save it to thier phone or SD card and then they can pick which story they want to read

Comment: Why are you using a file to store data in phone, there is a sqlite db.

Comment: so that users can write their own stories on a web site that i have and then we save them into our SQL DB on our server, we thought of SQLlite but cause we wanted to let users be able to write a story on their computer we thought it would be best to do it this was

Answer (score 5):

Try this code to read that file which you have saved previously.

```
try{
    FileInputStream fIn = openFileInput("filename.txt");
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
    char[] inputBuffer = new char[len];
    //len is the length of that saved string in the file

    isr.read(inputBuffer);

    String readString = new String(inputBuffer);
 }catch(IOException e){

    }
```

Comment: thanks rakshi this will also work with the json data i pull from story_one.php without converting it?

Comment: so to convert it out of json i would use readString is the string i would be converting?

Comment: iv asked a new Q can you have a look please you really helped me out last time the link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370701/how-to-save-a-file-type-as-json-on-android-to-internal-memory